# Error while trying to import socket?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, ipython, python-import

I've recently installed python, ipython and pip, with pip I've installed the socket library, and plenty others, now I can't import socket while running python program through cmd but I can do it using ipython,
When I run ipython and I import socket everything works fine,
now I wrote a simple script, called "tcp.py" and all it contains is nothing but the following line

**Import Socket**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\dir\desktop\tcp.py", line 1, in <module>
  import socket
 File "C:\dir\desktop\socket.py", line 1, in <module>
  socket
NameError: name 'socket' is not defined
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 5):

You've made two mistakes:  the first is to have your own file named "socket.py".  This shadows the stdlib module, so when you `import socket`, it finds your file instead of the module in the stdlib.  The second mistake is that your "socket.py" file has the word `socket` in it.  This is what is actually causing your error: the word `socket` is undefined.

Delete your "socket.py" file, and any *.pyc files lying around, and the problem will be fixed.

If you read the traceback (error report) closely, you can see what's happened.