# Why is that HTTP request with Python not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, http

I am following the FreeCodeCamp Python class where the teacher introduces the following, quite simple, piece of code to make an HTTP request. In the video, the guy started it and has a result.

```
import socket

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('data.pr4e.org', 80))
cmd = 'GET http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n'.encode()
mysock.send(cmd)

while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if len(data) < 1:
        break
    print(data.decode())
mysock.close()
```

I create a file (.py extension and all) before launching a python3 filename.py command through my terminal and ... 2 traceback messages :

1. line 1, in 
   import socket
2. line 3, in 
   mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   AttributeError: partially initialized module 'socket' has no attribute 'AF_INET' (most likely due to a circular import)

I am pretty sure I am missing something awfully basic.

Could you help to see through, please?

Comment: are you sure you need those 2x \n at the end of http/1.0?

Comment: Nope, the teacher has it in his code: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zjyT9DaAjx4

Comment: `HTTP/1.0\n\n` should be `HTTP/1.0\r\n` (teachers can have typos in their slides). Also, I think that you need two sequences of `\r\n` to indicate that sending the headers has finished. So `HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n`

Comment: Thanks, I will try it! Do you know why is the traceback blocking on lines 1 and 3 with a mention of modules?

Comment: Also, `GET http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt HTTP...` is not a valid header line, at least not in HTTP/1.1. `http://` should not be in there and `data.pr4e.org` should go in the next header line as `Host: data.pr4e.org`. Maybe HTTP/1.0 is different here.

Comment: I should have asked the almighty Internet before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25476044/error-while-trying-to-import-socket
The name of the file was socket.py then it was messing up with the request.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think the correct command would be `cmd = 'GET /romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: data.pr4e.org\r\n\r\n'.encode()`